# skype like alert notification messages using win32 api

Tags: winapi, user-interface, skype

can anyone give me a clue on how one can make skype like notifications alert popups using win32 api's.

In window one can show balloon tips using  shell_notifyicon(..) but it doesn't have any look-and-feel.
I would be very thankful if someone guide me a little on this topic.Also how do we decorate  win32 windows as skype did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own. As a starting point, you can have a look at my code here:
[StatusBarMsgWnd.h](https://osdn.net/projects/commitmonitor/scm/svn/blobs/head/trunk/src/StatusBarMsgWnd.h)
[StatusBarMsgWnd.cpp](https://osdn.net/projects/commitmonitor/scm/svn/blobs/head/trunk/src/StatusBarMsgWnd.cpp)

Comment: The link does not work now, can you share the updated link please?